# Blender Error, *SAVED VERTICES COUNT DIFFERENT FROM CURRENT* in TK 17 3D Female Body

Tags: error

So! I'm new here, I created my account today, and i'm searching the internet a lot about this error, and i could not fin a way to fix it "SAVED VERTICES COUNT DIFFERENT FROM CURRENT"

So I will explain how the female body works in Blender (The one that matters here)

Body Female default (Body01): have 4362 Vertices / 4376 Faces / 8728 Edges
See:
[image]

So that, i edited my female body, and had to delete some vertices that were connected nowhere, and after that, when I went to save the body back to .TXX to put in the game, blender showed it had an error:
[image]

But, as you can imagine if I have 4362 vertices by default, and i could not delete them or add more, why there are some artists who can make models with less than base default verts / and higher than base default verts?

If anyone knows how to answer this, and teach me how to resolve the error, I would be very very grateful!!

Comment: This message seems to originate from the third party add-on you're using (TK17 Bodies Utility?). It's probably best to check what the documentation of the add-on says or contact the developer of the add-on if you believe that this is a bug.

Comment: Please add a link to addon in question, in question.

Comment: The Blender Addon link: https://www108.zippyshare.com/v/8OCSnQKv/file.html. And i don't know who is the developer of the this add-on, Is there any way to know?

Comment: does anyone have the answer?